# Did Anakin visit Tatooine during the time of the Clone Wars after delivering Rotta?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, the-clone-wars, anakin-skywalker, tatooine

I was wondering if there is any known visit by Anakin to Tatooine during the Clone Wars, after the incident with Rotta where he has to go back to deliver the huttlet to Jabba.

Is there any mentions of Anakin going back to Tatooine after this? Willing or unwilling visits to his home world? The Hutts play a pretty constant part in Clone Wars, but he could also have always found a way to get out of those missions. Anything in Legends?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both canon and legends, I cannot find any reference of him going back to Tatooine during the Clone Wars after he rescued Rotta.